# How to structure a large routine when subtasks have strong interdependence

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

Dear StackOverflow :)

I am trying to implement a sort of pattern matching routine, that maps tree structures onto other tree structures in a specific way. Unfortunately the routine has to be very flexible, so that this operation is very non-trivial.
I can intuitively divide this large amount of work into smaller portions that can be handled sequentially, but I am having trouble to bring structure into the code I write. These subtasks have a very strong interdependence, so that if I break up the large function into smaller ones I need very much state information to get things right. This adds a lot of extra code and makes things hard to oversee - and, I am afraid, might reduce compiler optimization.
If I however choose to implement everything into a single large function, I am having problems with the "program flow" - I have to use a lot of goto statements (which I can mask away into something more pretty, but the problem still remains).

Now in general: How do you attack such problems that are "large"? Can you give me some hints about what I could look into?

Comment: In C or C++? You can always create a struct with the information you want to pass around. In C++ you can use references

Comment: @RedX Yes, but these structs need to contain a __lot__ of state information. This makes things a little ugly. The question is more about general style than specific language-features, though such might be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering for C++, but the principles should be transferable.

I'd say the solution here is to realise that C++ objects don't have to correspond to "tangible" things. Why not represent the matching task as a class instead of a function?

Basically, create a noncopyable class with a public "driver" function. The subtasks (smaller portions) can be represented as non-public member functions of that class, and they can share data via the class's data members.

Something like this:

```
bool patternsMatch(Pattern a, Pattern b) {
  return PatternMatcher(a, b).match();
}


class PatternMatcher
{
public:
  PatternMatcher(Pattern a, Pattern b);
  bool match() {
    subtask1();
    subtask2();
    return res;
  }
private:
  bool res;
  Pattern a, b;
  int something_subtasks_share;
  float more_shared_data;
  void subtask1();
  void subtask2();
};
```

Comment: Love this idea :) Feels kind of stupid though not to have thought of this before, since I've done the exact same thing dozens of times. I guess I lost focus trying to think too deeply too early...